# Finding JSON path inside object

Tags: javascript, json

How to check in an JSON object, the input path is present or not?

```
var obj = {
  "schemaOne": {
    "name": "abc",
    "Path": "i.abc",
    "count": 5347,
    "subFolders": [

    ]
  },
  "schemaTwo": {
    "name": "cde",
    "Path": "i.cde",
    "count": 0,
    "subFolders": [
      {
        "name": "efg",
        "Path": "",
        "count": 0,
        "subFolders": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "hij",
        "Path": "i.hij",
        "count": 1,
        "subFolders": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

var inputpath = "obj.count";
```

After doing several research I came across below code. Here in this code, `o.Path` is known to the user. But I want to modify the code so tat dynamically check `obj.count` is present in JSON object or not?

```
function upd(o, path, count) {
  if (o.Path == path) {
    o.count = count;
  } else {
    var arr;
    if (Array.isArray(o)) arr = o;
    else if (o.subFolders) arr = o.subFolders;
    else return;
    for(var j=0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      upd(arr[j], path, count);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Teemu obj variable contains the JSON object

Comment: Nope, `obj` is a JavaScript object, it has nothing to do with data interchange formats.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, neither the use case. As someone told u, `obj` is a JavaScript object, not a JSON.

If I understood correctly, you want to check if a path, espressed as string (such as "obj.count") exists in that object.

A very fast but **not safe** solution (`eval` is evil and should be avoided almost in every case) could be:

```
if(eval(inputpath)){
    //... do something
}
```

In alternative, I suggest you to write a function that gets an object and a string (path) as parameter, parses the string path and check if the object contains such path.

Start from here: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: I tried the code but for array index which is unknown it is throwing undefined [ http://jsfiddle.net/user87267867/uLL0a9u0/ ]

Comment: well, if the index it's unknown, that's not a valid path, and you can't use it. In your example, try `schemaTwo.subFolders[0].name` instead